# Force deletion of OneDrive synced file (Windows Explorer)

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business, synchronization

We are syncing (parts) of a 140 GB SharePoint library to several different clients with OneDrive. The files need to be physically available on the local hard drives.

When somebody is deleting a file and another client has this file opened, then the deleted file re-appears after a while again. This leads to many abandoned or duplicate files in our library. Is there a way to "force" the deletion of a file or directory? Deleting the files via SharePoint Online (the web browser) is not accepted by the clients, because it is too laborious.

Answer (score 0):

1.You could try to log into OneDrive or SharePoint online (i.e. [www.OneDrive.com](http://www.OneDrive.com) or .SharePoint.com and delete the files directly

2.Give all users CONTRIBUTE or MEMBER permissions, then wait a few hours for all the changes to sync to all the users, then delete the files / folders from your desktop or documents.

For more details, you could refer to:
https://www.urtech.ca/2021/01/solved-files-synced-to-onedrive-keep-reappearing-after-deletion/

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: As I said, deleting it from SharePoint/OneDrive Online is too laborious and the staff already has MEMBER permissions. :(

Comment: Further on, via SharePoint Online we can only delete single files and not entire directories. SharePoint complains that the directory needs to be empty before deleting it.